# Create button to copy row from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have Worksheet 1, with columns A to D.

I would like to create a button executing row to be copied to Worksheet 2, as soon as cell C in Worksheet 1 is populated.

I have no experience in Excel at all, so far I found and altered this macro code for my needs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I try to create a button to execute this macro, it would never work. Could anyone help me solve this, please.

Comment: This already does what you want, If you want to execute this macro on button press then move this code to `Button Click event` http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? Read more about `Worksheet_Change` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then _
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Rows(lRow)

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If the code still doesn't work then from the VBA Editor, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the immediate window and type this

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and now the code should work.

[image]

Comment: Siddharth, thank you for your answer, but the macro you wrote doesn't seem to work for me. The code I've added in my question: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
End Sub  works for me but I don't know how to assign this macro to a button so the macro would only be executed when the button is pressed. Any idea? Thanks, Jost

Comment: The above code is tried and tested. So "doesn't seem to work for me" doesn't give me enough information to help you :)

Comment: Also, the problem with my code is, the entire row is copied into Sheet 2 even if "delete" key is pressed in the column C - what I want is the row to only be copied when quantity is added (let's say 10). Also, I would like the row to be deleted from sheet 2 if the quantity is deleted from row C in sheet 1. Thanks, Jost

Comment: Siddharth - you are right. Actually nothing happens in Sheet 2 using this macro. But I do get "Subscript out of range" message when I put in number in column C.

Comment: Did you change `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` to reflect the correct sheet? else you will get the error that you mentioned above

Comment: I just renamed my Sheets back to Sheet1 and Sheet2 and the error is gone. Still nothing happens in Sheet2.

Comment: Siddharth, thank you for your help. Just wanted you to know I solved my problem. Have a good day.